# ajax function parameter success

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Is it possible to get and print id which I a passing in AJAx function. Like in below example, I am passing id in getOrder function. I have to get id in OnSuccess , please guide.

Thanks

```
 <script type = "text/javascript">
    function getOrder(id) { 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "page2.aspx/getOrderID",
           data:  '{  id:"' + id + '"  }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function(response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    }
    function OnSuccess(response) {

       document.getElementById('span1').innerHTML = response.d; 


    }
    </script>
```

Comment: You are already making dataType:"json, so in your `getOrder`, make `id` a part of your returned json string, and access it via `response.id`

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces - you confused me because JSON is a text format.  The `response` argument here is a Javascript object.  Yes, you could add another property to the response object if you wanted.  I'd personally send a separate argument rather than add a new property to the response because the `id` isn't part of the response so I think it makes the code clearer to keep them separate, but either could work.

Comment: @jfriend00, thank you I understand now. In the future i will be using your approach.

Answer (score 1):

When you call an external function, the `id` argument will not naturally be available to it because it the `OnSuccess` function is in a different scope.  But, you can pass that value to OnSuccess if you want like this:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function getOrder(id) { 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "page2.aspx/getOrderID",
           data:  '{  id:"' + id + '"  }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
                OnSuccess(response, id);
            },
            failure: function(response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    }
    function OnSuccess(response, id) {
       document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = response.d; 
    }
```

Or, you can use an inline function which, because it is defined within the same scope, has direct access to the `id` argument:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function getOrder(id) { 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "page2.aspx/getOrderID",
           data:  '{  id:"' + id + '"  }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
                document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = response.d; 
            },
            failure: function(response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: thank you for this, +1. I am a newb, could you please confirm to me that the approach I mentionned in comment is bad (I am using it in all my website).thanks in advance

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces - I don't understand that comment.  That sounds like something different than the OP asked about.  Perhaps you should ask your own question about it and show your actual code.

Comment: I edited the comment, thank you for your time, and I will be posting as separate question